# Why does calling the original function from my hook fail?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg, c#, injection

I am trying to retrieve text from another program. I used *Ollydbg* to find the address for the function I need to hook to get the info. I used ***EasyHook*** to inject the code below.

The hook works fine until I call the original function. It crashes each time I do. I think it may have something to do with the return type of the function. Since I am new to reversing, I am having trouble determining the correct return type. I tried several different return types ranging from void to int. After the function returns, `EAX` points to a unicode string but the value isn't used. From what I read, `EAX` is where a returned variable would be stored.

**Update:**

I now see that this exception is occurring.

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at ServerDLL.Injector.DoSomeThingDelegate.Invoke(Int32 argument1, Int32 argument2)
   at ServerDLL.Injector.DoSomeThing(Int32 argument1, Int32 argument2)
```

Calling the function:

```
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00425373  |.  894424 04     MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX             ; /Arg2
00425377  |.  8B45 A8       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-58]            ; |
0042537A  |.  890424        MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX               ; |Arg1
0042537D  |.  E8 8EC3FFFF   CALL DoSomething;
00425382  |.  8B4D 8C       MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-74]
00425385  |.  8B45 A8       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-58]
```

```
static string DoSomeThing(int argument1, int argument2)
{
    Log.WriteLine(argument1);
    Log.WriteLine(argument2);
    DoSomeThingDelegate del = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(new IntPtr(0x421810), typeof(DoSomeThingDelegate)) as DoSomeThingDelegate;
    if (del == null) return "";
    return del(seatnumber, stack); 
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
delegate string DoSomeThingDelegate(int argument1, int argument2);

public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InArg1)
{
    CreateRecvHook = LocalHook.Create(new IntPtr(0x421810), new  DoSomeThingDelegate(DoSomeThing), this);
    CreateRecvHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
}
```

Comment: The error may be caused due to the improper calling convention (`cdecl`, `stdcall`, `fastcall` etc) rather than the return type. From the code dump, it looks more of a `stdcall` as the stack pointer is not adjusted.

Comment: It seems EasyHook must use cdecl, stdcall, or thiscall. It still crashed with the same exception after changing to the other calling conventions though.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you want to hook another program, but then you're creating a process-local hook? After skimming the docs, I think you need `RemoteHooking`.

Comment: That code is in the DLL that I am injecting. It is how all the examples I have seen are done. I use RemoteHooking.Inject to inject it though. Also, it gets injected fine. I can retrieve the values I need. The problem is with calling the original function. When it is called, I get the exception.